# Why is the general case easier when proving that finite sets in general position may be described as the zero locus of quadratic polynomials?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

I have a problem while studying the proof of the following theorem (Thm 1.4 in *Algebraic Geometry, A first course* by Joe Harris):

If $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is any collection of $d \leq 2n$ points in general position, then $\Gamma$ may be described as the zero locus of quadratic polynomials.

Here is a summary of the proof: Suppose $q$ is a point such that every quadratic polynomial vanishing on $\Gamma$ vanishes at $q$. We shall show that $q\in \Gamma$. Note that for any partition $\Gamma=\Gamma_1\cup\Gamma_2$ of $\Gamma$ into $n$-point sets, $q$ lies in the union of the hyperplanes spanned by points of $\Gamma_1$ or $\Gamma_2$. Now let $S=\{p_1,\ldots,p_k\}$ be any minimal subset of $\Gamma$ such that $q$ lies in their span. Then $q$ lies in the span of $p_1$ and any $n−1$ of the points in $\Gamma−S$, from which we deduce that $q=p_1$.

The proof deals with the case when $d=2n$, and says that the general case is easier. Why is that?

Comment: The specific answer will probably depend on the method of proof that Harris uses. Can you outline the argument? (Do note that [questions should be self-contained](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2675) here, so that's another reason to include these details.)

Comment: OK. Suppose q is a point such that every quadratic polynomial vanishing on $\Gamma$ vanishes at $q$. We shall show that $q \in \Gamma$. Note that for any partition $\Gamma=\Gamma_1 \cup \Gamma_2$ of $\Gamma$ into $n$-point sets, $q$ lies in the union of the hyperplanes spanned by points of $\Gamma_1$ or $\Gamma_2$. Now let $S=\left\{p_1, \dots, p_k\right\}$ be any minimal subset of $\Gamma$ such that $q$ lies in their span. Then $q$ lies in the span of $p_1$ and any $n-1$ of the points in $T-S$, from which we deduce that $q=p_1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $d\leq n$, we may restrict our attention to the $\Bbb P^{d-1}$ spanned by the $d$ points we have, which is cut out by linear equations. Squaring these equations, we see that if we can solve the problem for $d$ points in $\Bbb P^{d-1}$, we can solve the problem for our original $d$ points in $\Bbb P^n$. So we may assume that $n+1\leq d\leq 2n$, and in the case that $d<2n$ we may let $\Gamma = \Gamma_1\cup \Gamma_2$ be a non-disjoint union of sets of cardinality $n$. The rest of the proof goes through from there.